# Escape ! in bash

Tags: linux, bash

I have a complex command bash and my password has a `!`. I can't just change the password

```
... command bla bla -p !MYPASSWORD!
```

throws me an error because it interprets the ! as a command.

How do I escape this? I tried `\!MYPASSWORD\!` without success

Comment: using single quotes around your password should do the trick

Comment: [Did you already search and try this? (Click me)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27216951/how-to-escape-the-bang-character-in-linux-bash-shell)

Answer (score 0):

Single quotes ('') are used to preserve the literal value of each character enclosed within the quotes.